# Issue with the survey list settings?

Tags: feature, survey-list, feature-stapling

Have created a feature(list provisioning) to update the "showuser" property of the survey list and stappled on the webapplication, it works perfectly fine and sets the list property when the survey list is created. However, facing the issue when accessing and saving(without any changes) the general setting of the survey list, it actually resets the showuser property to false. Is that an expected behavior? how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The General Settings contains the "Show user names in survey results?" which is the ShowUser property.

I just did a quick test then using PowerShell and a simple survey and the value stuck when changing it both in PowerSell and in the browser general settings page.

Here is my powershell script to test:

```
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://mysite")
$web = $site.RootWeb
$survey = $web.Lists["Mysurvey"]
$survey.ShowUser = $false
$survey.Update()
```